# Using PHP to check MySQL for multiple products

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my current code:

```
<?php

if (!defined("WHMCS"))
        die("This file cannot be accessed directly");


function limitOrders($vars) {
        if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT packageid FROM `tblhosting` WHERE `userid` = '{$_SESSION['uid']}'")) > 0) {

                if($packageid = '1') {
                global $errormessage;
                $errormessage = "<li>Sorry, you already have a Free VPS account and there's a limit of one per user.</li>";
                }
        }
}
add_hook("ShoppingCartValidateCheckout", 1, "limitOrders");
?>
```

This is the line in question specifically:

```
if($packageid = '1') {
```

When I originally started using this code I wanted to limit people from ordering the same product more than once.  The `packageid` for that specific product is `1`.

However, I now need to limit people from ordering about 5 different products, each with a different 'packageid'.  Is there a way I can simply modify the code above to check for these package IDS instead of just one:  1, 2, 6, 7, 10

Comment: You're assigning instead of comparing. Do `if($packageid == '1')`

Comment: Avoid using `mysql`. Use `mysqli` or even better `PDO`.

Comment: Just a warning, you shouldn't be using the `mysql` class in PHP anymore, use `mysqli` or PDO instead.  More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Comment: The code above works for limit people from ordering packageid 1 multiple times.  But I need to also limit people from ordering package ids 2, 6, 7, 10 more than once as well.

Comment: `if (in_array($packageid, array(1,2,6,7,10)) { do_something(); }`?

Comment: Unfortunately, WHMCS uses MySQL so its not feasible for him/her to use MySQLi :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($packageid == '1' || $packageid == '2' || $packageid == '6'/* ETC */) {
    // CODE
}
```

Or, even better:

```
if(in_array($packageid, array(1,2,6,7,10)){
    // CODE
}
```

Comment: The last version is the better one. You can remove the question mark :-)

Comment: @VMai Its obviously better for code readability, and easier to modify later on (or reference from another file/class), any other reasons?

Comment: Isn't that enough? But you could add that the array for the lookup could be generated elsewhere.

Comment: But have a look, what he's done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581366/how-to-show-php-variable-in-hyperlink

Comment: @VMai And he's still using just one = (assigning). /Facepalm.