# How to show PHP variable in hyperlink?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to echo a variable so it shows in my hyperlink.  Here's my current code:

```
<?php

if (!defined("WHMCS"))
        die("This file cannot be accessed directly");


$customerserviceid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `tblhosting` WHERE `userid` = '{$_SESSION['uid']}'");

function limitOrders($vars) {
        if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT packageid FROM `tblhosting` WHERE `userid` = '{$_SESSION['uid']}'")) > 0) {

                if($packageid = '1' || $packageid = '2' || $packageid = '3' || $packageid = '4' || $packageid = '5' || $packageid = '6' || $packageid = '7' || $packageid = '8' || $packageid = '9' || $packageid = '10') {
                global $errormessage;
                $errormessage = "<li>It looks like you already have an account!  Please <a href='http://mywebsite.com/upgrade.php?type=package&id=$customerserviceid'>click here</a> to upgrade or downgrade your account.</li>";
                }
        }
}
add_hook("ShoppingCartValidateCheckout", 1, "limitOrders");
?>
```

I tried adding `$customerserviceid` into the URL on line 14 but it just shows blank so I'm guessing that I didn't add something correctly.  When I run the query in phpMyAdmin it does show what I'm wanting so the query itself should be correct...

Comment: `mysql_query` doesn't return a string, it returns a resource. You have to call `mysql_fetch_array` to get the row from the database, and then index that to get the ID. And you need a `global` statement to be able to access a variable assigned outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the results from the query results, and then use `global` to access the global variable.

```
<?php
if (!defined("WHMCS"))
        die("This file cannot be accessed directly");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `tblhosting` WHERE `userid` = '{$_SESSION['uid']}'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$customerserviceid = $row['id'];

function limitOrders($vars) {
    global $customerserviceid;
    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT packageid FROM `tblhosting` WHERE `userid` = '{$_SESSION['uid']}'")) > 0) {

        if($packageid = '1' || $packageid = '2' || $packageid = '3' || $packageid = '4' || $packageid = '5' || $packageid = '6' || $packageid = '7' || $packageid = '8' || $packageid = '9' || $packageid = '10') {
        global $errormessage;
        $errormessage = "<li>It looks like you already have an account!  Please <a href='http://mywebsite.com/upgrade.php?type=package&id=$customerserviceid'>click here</a> to upgrade or downgrade your account.</li>";
        }
    }
}
add_hook("ShoppingCartValidateCheckout", 1, "limitOrders");
?>
```

Comment: I just tried that and it still seems to show up blank when hovering over the link.  Could it be that maybe `$customerserviceid` should be echoed or something like that...

Comment: No, it couldn't be. The variable is expanded when the string is assigned. If you echo the string, it will include the variable's value. Are you sure the query is finding something?

Comment: Have you called `session_start()` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: You are totally right, that was a mistake on my end and it's working perfectly now with your code.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fetch the data you just did a query to select the data from the database but you didn't printed result you may can use this :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `tblhosting` WHERE `userid` = '{$_SESSION['uid']}'");
$customerserviceid=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query returns a resourcse. You need to fetch data from the resourse. Yor can do it like this.

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `tblhosting` WHERE `userid` = '{$_SESSION['uid']}'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$customerserviceid = $row['id'];
```

This should work.